# Get status error from wget if remote file is not newer than local

Tags: wget

When doing `wget -c http://example.com/foo` to periodically update a file, is there any way to get an error status from `wget` if the file has not been updated since last download?

Something like:

```
$ wget --give-error-if-file-is-not-updated -c http://example.com/foo
$ echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 2):

`wget --timestamping` will conditionally download the file, depending on whether the remote timestamp changed, but the exit code is `0` either way. It indicates that you got what you asked for. Testing the exit code, you can only detect syntax and protocol errors.

Instead, detect that the file was not updated since last download by looking at the file date before and after. The following shell script fragment shows how you can turn this into the exit code you asked for.

```
OLD=` date -r$FILE +%s 2>/dev/null `  # capture age of file before
wget --timestamping $FILE || exit $?  # update file, die on error
NEW=` date -r$FILE +%s 2>/dev/null `  # capture age of file after
[ "$NEW" = "$OLD" ] && exit 1         # compare ages, die when they match
```

If you execute this, then `echo $?`, you will see the `wget` exit code when the `wget` fails, and you will still see `1` when the `wget` succeeds but the files match.

Value of the expression `date -r$FILE +%s 2>/dev/null` is age of `$FILE` in seconds since epoch, or an empty string when the information is absent (as when the file is missing). This is a convenient form of the age when you want to make a comparison.

The `--timestamping` option is not essential to the code fragment. This is because `wget` sets the local file timestamp to match the remote file timestamp, whether or not you use the option. The option merely keeps `wget` from making a redundant file transfer when the remote file has not changed.

Answer (score -1):

Wget calls this feature "time-stamping". It's documented at https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Time_002dStamping. To use it, just add `-N` or `--timestamping` to your command line: `wget --timestamping -c http://example.com/foo`.

Comment: `wget -N` returns status 0 (which means "no error") when the file is not modified, at least when I tried. Please elaborate.